# Flutter Cannot build iOS on vscode 2020

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

flutter run

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
Command line invocation:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -list

xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/iven/Desktop/user-app/ios contains 2 projects, including multiple projects with the current
extension (.xcodeproj). Specify the project to use with the -project option.
Command: /usr/bin/xcodebuild -list

Comment: I removed duplicated files and run this:
sudo rm -Rf /Users/iven/.pub-cache
sudo rm -Rf packages 
rm ios/Podfile  
flutter clean

and flutter run then I got this:

....

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.

Answer (score 0):

for who come later I discovered the solution later by changing the:
from: flutter_svg: ^0.17.x
to: flutter_svg: ^0.18.0